# Can SSD boost the speed of Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

Anyone knows if installing a SSD drive can speed up Cygwin in Windows?

Cygwin is essential to my daily work and for some reason I cannot switch to Linux. But the slowness of Cygwin really bugs me. I'm wondering if I should invest a SSD to gain productivity.

For example, compiling a LaTeX file is very slow compared to the speed under Linux. Starting `ipython` is noticeable slow too, similar to `R` and `octave` prompts. Updating plugins in `vim` using `vim-plug` is slow, etc, etc.

Comment: in what way is Cygwin slow?  You say you cant switch to Linux, what about a Linux VM?

Answer (score 0):

While a SSD *will* increase the overall speed of you machine, will it increase the speed of Cygwin?  Probably.  Reading from and writing to the disk will be much faster.  This means compiling your LaTex files will be faster.  How much?  Hard to say.

IMO, a SSD is a good investment if you want to increase speed on any disk related activity.